# Scala: Which is better - distinct then union or union then distinct?

Tags: arrays, list, scala, distinct, union

If I have two lists:

- listA - 1 million strings,
- listB - 1 million strings

and I want to merge them to a third listC that has only unique values from both the above lists, what approach out of the following is better:

1. Take a distinct() of both listA and listB before unionizing to listC OR,
2. Generate unionized listC and then apply distinct on listC

Does the same logic also apply to Arrays?

Comment: More of a side note, but approach 1 does not guarantee listC only contains distinct values as duplicates between listA and listB will be preserved as part of unioning two lists. You would also need to perform a distinct on the resultant listC with option 1 to guarantee distinct values in the result list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the `distinct` implementation:

```
def distinct: Repr = {
  val b = newBuilder
  val seen = mutable.HashSet[A]()
  for (x <- this) {
    if (!seen(x)) {
      b += x
      seen += x
    }
  }
  b.result()
}
```

It uses mutable structures for performance reasons.

So if performance is an issue, you can implement your distinct union the same way:

```
def distinctUnion[E](listA: Seq[E], listB: Seq[E]): Seq[E] = {
  val b = Seq.newBuilder[E]
  val seen = mutable.HashSet[E]()
  for (x <- listA) {
    if (!seen(x)) {
      b += x
      seen += x
    }
  }
  for (x <- listB) {
    if (!seen(x)) {
      b += x
      seen += x
    }
  }
  b.result()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the union first, but you want to do this in a lazy manner to avoid creating in memory the unioned collection. Something like this should work:

```
val listC = (listA.view union listB).distinct.toList
```

Computationally this is probably going to wind up doing something very similar to what Jean posted, but it is a bit nicer since it makes better use of the Scala collections library.